# What is the class of MySQL object?

Tags: php, mysql

If we use `mysql_fetch_object`, it returns recordset as an object.
I want to know that is this object is object of some particular class?

Or simply, returned object by `mysql_fetch_object` is object of which class?

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of the object and you will see the class :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation itself states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php), that the resulting class will be `stdClass` or whatever you pass as the second parameter to the function.